# How to stop Jquery hover in media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have created a nav with jquery hover effects.

The nav works, the only problem is when you make the screen 800px wide or less and press the red box to display the toggle nav. The hover menu is picking up the jquery from the full width menu.

How can I stop the jquery hover menu from not picking up the hover state of the main menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8zqS/2/

```
/*  MAIN MENU DROPDOWN
===================================*/
$("#toggle-nav").click(function () {
    $("#nav").slideToggle('slow');
});
/*  MAIN SETTINGS SHOW AND HIDE
===================================*/

$("#user-profile").hover(function(){
    $('.tabs').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check the width of the browser in your hover handler:

```
$("#user-profile").hover(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() > 800 ) $('.tabs').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. is there another way as when im move the screen to make it responsive the navigation isnt reactive unless I refresh the page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm not seeing an issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/n8zqS/3/

Comment: If you check the media query navigation its lost the hover state menu.? until you refresh the page

Comment: Again, 'its lost the hover state menu' is not super clear, but I think this is more an issue with the slideToggle function you're using. If you hide the dropdown menu in the smaller screen, when you expand it, it stays hidden. That's a problem that exists unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Paul Designer, If you are using jQuery it will not take place until the page is reloaded unless you give it an on-resize function as well. This is not life or death though, not many people resize their desktop window down to a mobile size for fun. :p